# Set permissions for GlassFish application (a war deployment)

Tags: java, authentication, deployment, solr, glassfish

I am totally new to java/GlassFish deployment. I am using solr for the search functions of my rails app. i can able to set the mater password for the domain from the shell. It was fine. It greets with authentication screen when i tried to launch GlassFish portal.

But i could't find how to set the permissions for my deployed solr war instance. Can someone help me how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of [tutorials that outline what you need to do to secure a web app deployed onto GlassFish](https://www.google.com/search?q=secure%20a%20web%20application%20deployed%20on%20glassfish).

This is a [tutorial on developing a secure a web app that you are creating in NetBeans for deployment onto GlassFish](http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/web/security-webapps.html).

This is [chapter from the Java EE 6 Tutorial describes how to secure access to a web app](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bncbx.html).